# DevExpress GridView Exported Excel Sheet Adding Custom Heading and Logo

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, crystal-reports, devexpress

I am using ExportToXlsx() method in order to export data from GridView to Excel Sheet.
this seams to export and format the data just fine, even my conditional formatting is being exported as is.
The only thing I would like to know is that how do I add a logo and header in that excel file without having to add it manually. Like in a Crystal Report we can add these things at the design time. Is there something that can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `PrintableComponentLink` and write a `CreateReportHeaderArea` event handler:

```
private void button_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        var y = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
        y.Component = gridControl1;
        y.CreateReportHeaderArea += y_CreateReportHeaderArea;

        if (saveFileDialog_Report.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog_Report.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {
                y.ExportToXlsx(saveFileDialog_Report.FileName);
            }               
        }   
}


void y_CreateReportHeaderArea(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
{
        DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextBrick brick;

        brick = e.Graph.DrawString("My Report Title Here", Color.Navy, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 40), DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None);

        brick.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);

        brick.StringFormat = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BrickStringFormat(StringAlignment.Center);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Milen's answer that added the header, I was also able to add an image to the report like below

```
    void y_CreateReportHeaderArea(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
{
 Image newimage = Image.FromFile("path");

        DevExpress.XtraPrinting.ImageBrick iBrick;
        iBrick = e.Graph.DrawImage(newimage, new RectangleF(0,0,40,40));

DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextBrick brick;

        brick = e.Graph.DrawString("My Report Title Here", Color.Navy, new RectangleF(40, 0, 500, 40), DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None);

        brick.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);

        brick.StringFormat = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BrickStringFormat(StringAlignment.Center);

}
```

just make sure that you keep the coordinates and size correct so the image and text dont overlap.